# Regex: Recognizing and removing lists and menus

Tags: regex, nlp

Before I write my own method, I am curious whether there is a regex that can help me.

**The Context**

I am cleaning raw text prior to running statistical analyses on the terms. The text is from websites and thus includes menus (many menus from many websites).

A typical list/menu appears as follows (Except with one line break between items):

> STUDENT SERVICES
>
> Guidance & Support
>
> Core Services
>
> Admissions & Records
>
> Financial Aid
>
> Counseling
>
> Assessment Testing
>
> Kickstart Orientation
>
> Tutoring
>
> Career & Transfer Center
>
> Student Welcome Center

**The Task at Hand**
I want to remove all lists

I need to remove text blocks where there is a line break after  every first second, third or fourth word, but only if this pattern repeats 3 or more times consecutively (I don't want to remove single short sentences such as "Students always succeed.")

Can a regex identify this pattern?

NOTE: I am working in java.

**UPDATE with sample text**

[[[I WANT TO REMOVE THIS LIST]]]
Offices & Services

Student Services

Activities & Athletics

Records & Registration

Costs & Financial Aid

Compliance & Diversity

Alumni

Faculty/Staff Resources

BMCC Foundation

Human Resources

BMCC Homepage>Academics>Health Education>Course Listings

[[[I WANT TO REMOVE THIS LIST]]]
Health Education Home

Course Listings

Faculty

[[[I WANT TO REMOVE THIS LIST]]]
Community Health Education

Gerontology

School Health Education

Public Health

Visit Admissions

Course Listings

[[[I WANT TO KEEP TEXT BELOW]]]
The following courses are offered by the Department of Health Education.

2CRS., 2HRS,  0 LAB HRS.
HED 100
Health Education

This is an introductory survey course to health education. The course provides students with the knowledge, skills, and behavioral models to enhance their physical, emotional, social, intellectual and spiritual health as well as facilitate their health decision-making ability. The primary areas of instruction include: health and wellness; stress; human sexuality; alcohol, tobacco and substance abuse; nutrition and weight management; and physical fitness. Students who have completed HED 110 - Comprehensive Health Education will not receive credit for this course.

3CRS., 3HRS,  0 LAB HRS.
HED 110
Comprehensive Health Education

This course in health educations offers a comprehensive approach that provides students with the knowledge, skills, and behavioral models to enhance their physical, emotional, social, intellectual and spiritual health as well as facilitate their health decision-making ability. Areas of specialization include: alcohol, tobacco and abused substances, mental and emotional health, human sexuality and family living, nutrition, physical fitness, cardiovascular health, environmental health and health care delivery. HED 110 fulfills all degree requirements for HE 100. Students who have completed HED 100 - Health Education will not receive credit for this course.

Comment: Hi, can you add an example? I mean, what is the input and the desired output?

Comment: "...line break after every first second, third or fourth word..." is the number of words important?

Comment: The input would be the plain text (not html) from a webpage. ... a bit long to show here. The list shown in the question is typical of what needs removing from the text.

The output would be the same plain text BUT with all lists removed.

Comment: is the number of words important?
The heuristic is that entries in menus and lists are four words or fewer. Since I am working with big data, removing 90% of lists suffices, and the "4 words or fewer" rule should fulfill that purpose

Comment: @Jake I mean, will a line with 5+ words not be subject to this, or do you mean there will only ever be lines with 1-4 words?

Comment: There will be (many) lines of 5 plus words. I will add a sample to the question after all :)

Comment: So, you have a 'big' document, and in other hand you have different lists of words/phrases that you would like to remove from the 'big' document but only if there is more than three occurrences?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Oh, I see ! And thats why the 'new line'/'new line' format is important ! Thanks for the clarification, @kirkpatt post and awesome answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the part about the number of words is not important, try a regex pattern of `(([A-Za-z& ])*(\n|\r|\r\n)){5,}`, example [here](https://regex101.com/r/UORYwR/2).

Change that five quantifier as needed, that is just an example. A five would not match two lines with an extra newline or a three line list without an ending new line.

Comment: Also note that I assume the only special characters you have are spaces and ampersands. Add there if needed.

Comment: Needs a tweak or two but this is totally magic. Wow! Thanks a million. I'd upvote you twice if I were allowed